# I can see the Minecraft .jar files but no mod folder

Tags: minecraft

I can see the .jar files in Minecraft, but I don't see a mod folder.

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

```
xdg-open ~/.minecraft
```

Inside that folder you should see a folder named *Mods* which is marked by a red arrow in the screenshot. That's where you'll put any Minecraft mods you want to install. If you don't see a Mods folder, make sure you've installed [Minecraft Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) and restarted Minecraft.

[image]